# Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 in React in Mac

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, sass

I think I am using appropriate node/npm/node-sass versions but still I get this error - "Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0" while running **npm start** comment. I am not sure what is this 4.0.0 version. it is not in any of my version given below.

Below are installed versions

```
Node version - 16.15.0
NPM version - 8.11.0
Node Sass version - 7.0.1
```

Below is package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.6",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "normalize-scss": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.52.1"
  }
}
```

Can anyone guess what is causing incompatible issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's your version of `sass-loader` which is incompatible. You can see the version you are using by going to:

```
node_modules > sass-loader > package.json
```

And then read what is written next to `"version"`.

---

Your project uses CRA, it means that it's `react-scripts` which deals with `sass-loader`. Updating your version of `react-scripts` should solve the problem.

Since you are using an old version, I recommend that you do the update progressively. You can start with the [v3.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v3.0.0) then [v4.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v4.0.0) and finally [v5.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v5.0.0).

**Don't forget to read the breaking changes for each release, as they may break other parts of your code.**

---

#### You also need to know that [Node Sass is deprecated](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated) and you should try to use Dart Sass instead.

Answer (score 3):

## Don't use node-sass anymore

`node-sass` has been deprecated. Use use `sass` instead.

You can uninstall the old it and only use `sass` with this commands

```
npm uninstall node-sass

npm install sass
```

**But if you want to use `node-sass` anyways**

You can use the following table to install the appropriate version `node-sass` for your installed node version which you can check by the command `node --version`

```
npm install node-sass@(your version)
```

[image]

Comment: `npm install sass` installs JavaScript library which is quite slow. I'd recommend Dart Sass binaries from: https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases